# Set/configure the EJB Timer Service’s DataSource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to use the Timer Service in EJB 3.1 in my app.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class StatelessTimerSessionBean {

    @Schedule(minute = "*", second = "0", dayOfMonth = "*", month = "*", year = "*", hour = "9-17", dayOfWeek = "Mon-Fri")
    public void myTimer() {
        System.out.println("Timer event: " + new Date());
    }
}
```

> ".. set the EJB Timer Service’s Timer DataSource setting to a valid JDBC resource.."

from [EJB Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4336/beahw/index.html)

I cannot figure out how to configure the Timer Datasource correctly?

The error I get when deploying is:

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Timer Service is not available
```

Running: glassfish-3.1.2.2

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it work to setup non-persistent timers? @Schedule(second="*/5", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)

Comment: It did not work. I just solved it I'm about to write the answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### 1. Example Database Setup

1. I use MySQL for my database.
2. Create the table `EJB__TIMER__TBL` from `{GF_HOME}/glassfish/lib/install/databases/ejbtimer_{DB_ENGINE}.sql`

DB_ENGINE  = e.g MySQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EJB__TIMER__TBL (
    `CREATIONTIMERAW`      BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    `BLOB`                 BLOB,
    `TIMERID`              VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
    `CONTAINERID`          BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    `OWNERID`              VARCHAR(255)  NULL,
    `STATE`                INTEGER       NOT NULL,
    `PKHASHCODE`           INTEGER       NOT NULL,
    `INTERVALDURATION`     BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    `INITIALEXPIRATIONRAW` BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    `LASTEXPIRATIONRAW`    BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    `SCHEDULE`             VARCHAR(255)  NULL,
    `APPLICATIONID`        BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_EJB__TIMER__TBL` PRIMARY KEY (`TIMERID`)
);
```

### 2. Server Configuration

[image: GlassFish Admin Console]

1. Start your GlassFish server admin console: usually `http://localhost:4848`
2. On your left navigate to **[Configurations] > [server-config] > [EJB Container]**
3. Then click the **TAB** up top **[EJB Timer Service]**
4. Then fill out **Timer Datasource**: with your JDBC Resource eg. [mysql-pu]. (  [***Note:*** Defaults to `jdbc/__TimerPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4336/beahw/index.html))
5. **Restart** the Server

### 3. The Result

```
...
INFO: [TimerBeanContainer] Created  TimerBeanContainer: TimerBean
INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TimerBean: [java:global/ejb-timer-service-app/TimerBean, java:global/ejb-timer-service-app/TimerBean!com.sun.ejb.containers.TimerLocal]
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [ejb-timer-service-app] at [/ejb-timer-service-app]
INFO: EJB5109:EJB Timer Service started successfully for data source [mysql-pu]
INFO: Setting DBReadBeforeTimeout to false
INFO: ==> Restoring Timers ... 
INFO: There are no EJB Timers owned by this server
INFO: <== ... Timers Restored.
...
```

### 4. Still Broken? TimerService just stopped working (it used to work)?

So this happened to me after a day full of "deploy on save". The TimerService was unavailable all of a sudden.

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /ejb-timer-service-app
Warning:   Cannot deploy or load EJBTimerService: org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Error in linking security policy for ejb-timer-service-app -- Inconsistent Module State
```

**[Solution Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11770611/532772)**

### 5. Useful Links

- [Oracle: To Deploy an EJB Timer to a Cluster](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beahw.html#gktqo)

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss/WildFly, you can follow these instructions:

[Mastertheboss.com: Creating clustered EJB 3 Timers](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/creating-clustered-ejb-3-timers)  
Published: 08 March 2015

Answer (score -3):

That sounds like the glassfish-3.1.2.2 does not support EJB3, try to use jboss 7.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24939/release-notes.htm